# Callback not called on Continuation Object

Tags: object, continuation

I am trying to invoke SOAP service using continuation. While I am able to successfully hit the service, my callback function is not called. Please help me know if there is any issue with it. Thanks

```
public Continuation doSave(){

    System.debug('request');
    Integer timeOut=20;//get form Custom Setting
    Continuation contObj=new Continuation(timeOut);
    contObj.continuationMethod='processResponse';
    Id entityIdentifier=policyRole.Id;
    String caseIdentifier='PolicyRoleUpdateForNewAccnt';
    AsyncPolicyManagementWebService.AsyncPolicyManagement_SOAP asynService=new AsyncPolicyManagementWebService.AsyncPolicyManagement_SOAP();
    PolicyManagementWebServiceSchema.PartyInput_Type payload=PolicyManagementWebServiceUtil1.getPartyInputType(entityIdentifier,caseIdentifier);
    asynService.JHHeader_request=PolicyManagementWebServiceUtil1.getRequestHeader(caseIdentifier);
    asynService.endpoint_x='http://policymanagement.getsandbox.com/Insurance/PolicyManagement_1.0';
    responseFuture=new AsyncPolicyManagementWebServiceSchema.UpsertPolicyPartyRole_response_elementFuture();
    responseFuture=asynService.beginUpsertPolicyPartyRole(contObj,policyNum,subDivisionId,subDivisionQualifier,subDivisionQualifierType,carrierAdminSystem,payload);

    return contObj;  
}

public Object processResponse(){
   System.debug('response');
   try{
     //response=new PolicyManagementWebServiceSchema.UpsertPolicyPartyRole_response_element();
     response=responseFuture.getValue();
     detailPageUrl=stdController.save();
     System.debug('page-'+detailPageUrl);
     System.debug(response);
     return detailPageUrl;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
     System.debug('Exception'+e.getMessage());
     return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume you are calling `doSave()` from a Visualforce page? Can you add an extract from your page around how the method is called? Also, what do the Apex logs show during the callout and response?